# Mapping native java Object to own implemented class

Tags: java, hibernate, object, mapping

I have a call to database using hibernate

```
List<Object> result = session.openSession().createSQLQuery(myNativeSQLQuery).list();
```

No I can iterate over that list

```
Iterator iter = result.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    Object[] item = (Object[]) iter.next();
}
```

But that Object is of no use for myself and so I want to have that object mapped on a class I implemented.

```
public class MyClass {

    private Long id;

    private String name

    private Set<MySecondClass> myList

    public void myFunc(){
        // do sth with that id or any other attribute mapped
    }   
}
```

I do not want to use hibernate annotations and stuff, because a defined class will be filled up with data by a xml file that defines native sql queries. That way I want to materialize the resulting document into mongodb for a fast data access.

An example of such an xml file you see below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mapping>
<resource>myResource</resource> <!-- the resource table in mysql where the base query is executed -->
<destination>myDestination</destination> <!-- the destination collection in mongodb -->

<document mapped="MyClass"> <!-- that docuemnt and the base query will be mapped on the class "MyClass"

    <base sql="select id, name from table1" />
    <reference id="_ID_" column="id" /> <!-- use the result from the base query and replace the placeholder _ID_ of all following sql querys with the value of id in that current iteration -->

    <lists>
        <myList mapped="MySecondClass" sql="select col1, col2 from table2 where referenceId=_ID_" /> <!-- each element of that listed will be mapped on MySecondClass and fills the property "myList"
    </lists>

</document>
```

Comment: It is quite unclear what you want to achieve. What does it mean to "map an object on a class"?

Comment: The Object I got from Hibernate has the type Object[] where all the columns are available. So from the query "select id, name from table1" I will get in each iteration an _Object[] obj_ where the column "id" is available at obj[0], but I want to map that on the id property

Comment: Yes, I know the select statement results in object arrays. What does it mean for you to 'map that on the id property'?

Comment: If you want Hibernate to return instances of your class, you should use HQL in the mode "from MyClass where ...". Otherwise you'll have to  do the copying from the object array into your bean yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It results that I do not need to copy/map an Object. I just can make use of the annotation *org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document* and the abtract class *com.mongodb.BasicDBObject* from spring data.

```
@org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document
public class BasicDocument extends BasicDBObject {

}
```

and after that I could create just do

```
BasicDocument doc = new BasicDocument();
doc.put("key", "value");
```

and store that doc into mongodb. that way I could even create the lists.